# Creating an HTML editor component with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

New to React, please point out if I've headed down the wrong track: I'm trying to build an HTML editor component, which so far looks like this:

```
var CopyEditor = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var pageBody = "<p>My HTML string ...";
    return (
      <form id="editForm" method="POST">
        <textarea id="editor" name="body" value=pageBody />
        <input type="submit" id="saveBt" value="save" class="button-primary" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

But I'm getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 6: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>      at http://localhost:8000/index.html
>
> var pageBody = '
>                              ^

My HTML string is being generated on the Server, and there's a newline where the carot is pointing in the error message. What SHOULD I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont really need `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with `textarea`. You can just use `value` prop:

http://jsfiddle.net/egkc7dbd/

```
var CopyEditor = React.createClass({
  onChange : function(){
  },
  render: function(){
    var pageBody = "<p>My HTML string ...";
    return (
      <form id="editForm" method="POST">
        <textarea id="editor" name="body" value="<p>My HTML string ..." onChange={this.onChange}/>
        <input type="submit" id="saveBt" value="save" className="button-primary" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<CopyEditor/>, document.body);
```

---

**UPDATE**

According to the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-textarea-value) you can have line breaks using `\n`. The first solution is missing `{}` around `value` prop.

new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwb50xu9/

```
var CopyEditor = React.createClass({
  onChange : function(){
  },
  render: function(){
    var pageBody = "<p> \n My HTML string ...";
    return (
      <form id="editForm" method="POST">
        <textarea id="editor" name="body" value={pageBody} onChange={this.onChange}/>
        <input type="submit" id="saveBt" value="save" className="button-primary" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<CopyEditor/>, document.body);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! That makes the code quite a bit cleaner. I realized that originally my pageBody var wasn't enclosed in quotes, so I did that, and am getting a different error than what I originally posted, which I've updated above.

Comment: Many thanks! I found that my error results from having linefeed characters (\u000a) in my string, which are ILLEGAL in JavaScript. I think once I replace them with newlines, I'll be set.

Comment: but textarea will not display HTML markup. It just displays as a string right ?